# Self-Type with private modifier

Tags: scala

I would like to implement a trait with a self-type like the following:

```
trait HasEquipment {
  this: {def loadEquipment: List[Equipment]} =>

  //more methods
}
```

Now i can mix this trait into classes and these classes have to define a "loadEquipment" Method:

```
case class Course(id: Long) extends HasEquipment {
    def loadEquipment: List[Equipment] = {
        //implementation
    }
}
```

However I don't want to expose to `loadEquipment` Method to everyone but only to the trait. So what i would like to do is make `loadEquipment` private in the Course class so that only the trait has access to it. Making it private prevents the trait from accessing the method.

Is there another way to make `loadEquipment` only accessible from within the trait?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you want a self-type here. An abstract, protected member works just as well:

```
trait HasEquipment {
  protected def loadEquipment: List[Equipment]
}

case class Course(id: Long) extends HasEquipment {
  override protected def loadEquipment: List[Equipment] = ???
}
```

As a side note, structural types in Scala make use of reflection, which is the reason why they're usually avoided.