# Self-type with private members: Limitation of Scala?

Tags: scala, self-type

I have a trait `Bar` that has a self-type to `Foo`.  `Bar` contains a member that only `Foo`, and not any of `Foo`'s children, should be able to access:

```
trait Foo {
  private val x = new X
}

trait Bar {
  this: Foo =>

  <protected> class X
}
```

I used `<protected>` to signify that I need an access modifier that allows `Foo` access to the class `X` but disallows access for all child classes.

(Note: I am aware that in this simplified example I could just declare `private class X` inside `Foo` and just get rid of `Bar` altogether, but that's not what I need.  This is a minimal, toy example — my production use case is that the class `X` is actually a very large (300+ line) private class definition, and I'd like to define the class in a separate file.)

Also note that this question was asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24778500/self-type-with-private-modifier) many years ago, but the accepted answer dodges the question altogether.  Finally, my question is *not* a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32905495/access-private-member-in-self-typed-trait-without-access-scope-leaking) — in fact, it's the reverse.

## Use case

I *could* define the above as:

```
trait Foo {
  private val x = new X

  private class X {
    ...
  }
}
```

But if class `X` is hundreds or thousands of lines long, I'd like it to be in a separate file — hence the self-type `Bar`.

## Bottom line

Is this possible?

If not, is this an inherent limitation of the Scala language, and is there a SIP or other plan to address it?

Comment: You are doing it backwards. If `Foo` (and _only_ `Foo`) accesses `X`, then why in the world you are defining it in `Bar`? Also, `x` is public, but it's type `X` is private .. that does not make very much sense

Comment: Good catch. Edited `x` to be private.  Also, the reason is so that the large file can be split into multiple files.

Comment: If `Foo` is so large und unwieldy, could it make sense to allocate an entire package for it, and then put both `Foo` and `Bar` (with inner `X`) into this package, and declare `X` to be package-private? Then, if the subclasses are not in the same package, then they won't have access to `X`.

Comment: If you want X to be in a separate file, it can't be inner to either `Foo` or `Bar`. Use the package approach in that case, as suggested above. If X is inner,it has to be inner to whatever is using it, it just doesn't make sense otherwise. In general, it seems that the real problem isn't that the class needs to be in a separate file, but rather that it is "large and unwieldy". I am guessing, your code would benefit more from refactoring it into smaller, more manageable classes, than it would from "hiding" it in a separate file.